# How to implement db operation in scala functional programming

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm quite new to Scala and functional programming. I have read that we are not supposed to make any side effect(Eg: DB and IO operation) in FP. I'm wondering how can we handle DB operation in Scala?

Comment: You can look at Doobie which is a pure functional JDBC layer for Scala https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie

Comment: Just sharing my two cents, even if the preferred thing to do is what Krzysztof said _(and it is what I would do too)_. IMHO, going full **FP** takes its time, and if you are just learning **Scala** that could be an overkill. Also, I would recommend first understanding the advantages of `IO` _(at least from a conceptual point of view)_ before using it just as "cargo cult". Thus, I would advice you to first learn **Scala** as a language, and then learn **FP** _(scala with cats is a great first option)_ and then learn how to convert side-effects in pure values _(cats-effect documentation)_.

Comment: For now, I would recommend you to just try to segregate your pure functions for the outside world. ensure your business logic is not contaminated with anything effectual, that is the first step. If you are able to reason about the 80% of your code, then `IO` will help you with the 20% remaining. - But once again, that is just my opinion :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez, much appreciated :)

Comment: There are purusts, fantasists and academics. Then there are people who realize no side effects means nothing at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to create a purely functional app, you can't do any side effects, but without side effect how can we do anything useful (write text to console, read data from the database, etc.)?

Basically, what we can do is *"cheating"* by wrapping all code that is not pure (is performing any side effects) in [effect](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/what-effects-effectful-mean-in-functional-programming) which is usually called *IO* monad. Impure actions wrapped with *IO* are not executed until explicitly started (usually by calling method named like *unsafeRun*). And since that wrapped actions are just values, you can return them from functions, assign to variables and do everything you would do with plain values:

```
import cats.effect.IO //you'd have to add cats-effect dependency to make this import work

val printHelloToConsole = IO(println("Hello")) //nothing is happening yet

printHelloToConsole.unsafeRunSync // starting performin effects
```

The main purpose of that action is an attempt to separate pure, functional code from impure parts of the application. Quote from Martin Odersky:

> The IO monad does not make a function pure. It just makes it obvious that it’s impure.

There are several implementations of *IO Monad* for Scala: **ZIO**, **Cats-Effect**, **Monix**. For pure functional database communication, you can use [Doobie](https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie) which works with any of these monads.

I would recommend you to watch that talk from John de Goes [FP to the max](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxudIMiOo68), it explains very well what is IO monad and how to use it.